# Why are let binders part of the kernel in Coq/Lean?

Tags: type-theory, theorem-provers

I've been looking into the implementations of CIC-based theorem provers - mainly Coq and Lean - and it seems that both of them have let binders as part of the kernel, with their own typing and reduction rules.

I get why let binders are useful, but it seems to me they could just be syntactic sugar:
`let x:T = y in z --> (fun x:T, z)(y)` Is there a type-theoretic reason they're in the kernel as a separate concept, or is it for implementation/software efficiency reasons?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`let` is not derivable as syntactic sugar in type theory. That only works if types cannot depend on `let`-defined names. For example, trying to desugar `let A : Set = Bool in λ (x : A). not x` yields `(λ (A : Set) (x : A). not x) Bool` which is ill-typed.

We can either add `let` to core syntax, or unfold all `let`-s during elaboration. The latter may cause a size explosion in elaboration output, and `let`-s are very useful in the surface language, so the straightforward solution is to have `let` as primitive.